# Redis memory fragmentation high even though Redis barely uses memory

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache

I'm a bit confused by the way Redis cache works. We've set up an Elasticache server on our AWS account, but every now and then we get High RSS warnings and our services get struck by a lot of timeout exceptions. When I run `memory doctor` on the redis server I get the following message:

> - Peak memory: In the past this instance used more than 150% the memory that is currently using. The allocator is normally not able to release memory after a peak, so you can expect to see a big fragmentation ratio, however this is actually harmless and is only due to the memory peak, and if the Redis instance Resident Set Size (RSS) is currently bigger than expected, the memory will be used as soon as you fill the Redis instance with more data. If the memory peak was only occasional and you want to try to reclaim memory, please try the MEMORY PURGE command, otherwise the only other option is to shutdown and restart the instance.

I don't understand why our fragmentation ratio is so high even though we use so little memory. From what I see we peaked at 3.34%. How is this possible? Did we break something in the configuration? Where should we start looking?

[image: AWS Elasticache monitoring]

These are the current memory stats:

```
# Memory
used_memory:60719304
used_memory_human:57.91M
used_memory_rss:77680640
used_memory_rss_human:74.08M
used_memory_peak:363901040
used_memory_peak_human:347.04M
used_memory_peak_perc:16.69%
used_memory_overhead:11326056
used_memory_startup:10499920
used_memory_dataset:49393248
used_memory_dataset_perc:98.35%
allocator_allocated:62149848
allocator_active:67325952
allocator_resident:73523200
used_memory_lua:31744
used_memory_vm_eval:31744
used_memory_lua_human:31.00K
used_memory_scripts_eval:0
number_of_cached_scripts:0
number_of_functions:0
number_of_libraries:0
used_memory_vm_functions:32768
used_memory_vm_total:64512
used_memory_vm_total_human:63.00K
used_memory_functions:184
used_memory_scripts:184
used_memory_scripts_human:184B
maxmemory:5140907060
maxmemory_human:4.79G
maxmemory_policy:volatile-lru
allocator_frag_ratio:1.08
allocator_frag_bytes:5176104
allocator_rss_ratio:1.09
allocator_rss_bytes:6197248
rss_overhead_ratio:1.06
rss_overhead_bytes:4157440
mem_fragmentation_ratio:1.28
mem_fragmentation_bytes:16984040
mem_not_counted_for_evict:0
mem_replication_backlog:0
mem_total_replication_buffers:0
mem_clients_slaves:0
mem_clients_normal:106592
mem_cluster_links:0
mem_aof_buffer:0
mem_allocator:jemalloc-5.1.0
active_defrag_running:0
lazyfree_pending_objects:0
lazyfreed_objects:0
```

Comment: Try playing around with the jemalloc's opt.narenas which can be set through environment vars. We are seeing a similar situation where when redis was running on a VM with 16 cores, it was running fine with the value of opt.narenas auto set to 64(4x16). But when it was run as a k8s pod, it started having memory fragmentation increase until it cross the memory limit of the container and got OOM killed. The only diff I can see is that it sees all the 96 cores on the baremetal and set the value of opt.narenas to 384(96x4). might be applicable if u r also running on VM with high no of cores.